# Pointer to a pointer (2D array) as input parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters, constants

I started studying C++ at university 2 months ago, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass a dynamic 2d array (pointer to pointer) to a function as an input parameter.
I have this dynamic 2d array:

```
int **p;
p = new int*[R];
for(i=0; i<R; i++)
    p[i] = new int[C];
```

Now I want to pass this pointer p to a function as an input parameter, using const. I mean that I want the function not to be able to modify the elements of the matrix.

I tried like that:

```
void func(const int **p) {
}
```

But i get this error:

> main.cpp:19:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'const
>   int**' [-fpermissive]
>
> main.cpp:9:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void func(const int**)' [-fpermissive]

I tryied using typedef and it works, but it's not constant.
If i do like that:

```
typedef int** abc;

void func(const abc p);

main() {
abc p;
...
func(p);
}
```

The source compiles but function 'func' is able to modify values of "p matrix"; I want p to be an input parameter, it has to be read-only!

Please, how can I pass a pointer-to-pointer to a function flagging the elements as read-only?

Thank you in advance for you help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `const int **p` should be a `const int * const *p`. The conversion from `const int **` to `int **` isn't allowed to be implicit, because it could violate the constness of the values being pointed to. To see why, look at the following code extract taken from the C standard (§6.5.16.1):

```
const char **cpp;
char *p;
const char c = 'A';

cpp = &p;       // constraint violation
*cpp = &c;      // valid
*p = 0;         // valid
```

If `cpp = &p` was a valid assignment, the subsequent code would be able to set the value of `c` to `0`, despite the value being a `const char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void func(const int * const *p) {
}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide me a short explaination of this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
typedef const int *cint_ptr_t  ;

void func(const cint_ptr_t  *p) {
}
```

Keep in mind that you want to be const the elements of your 2D array *and* the pointers to the beginning of each row